# Codeigniter javascript error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

i got script, that check's the user is available for registration:

**PHP:**

```
<?php  

if(isset($_POST['username']))//If a username has been submitted
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);//Some clean up :)

    $check_for_username = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    //Query to check if username is available or not

    if(mysql_num_rows($check_for_username))
    {
       echo '1';//If there is a  record match in the Database - Not Available
    }
    else
    {
        echo '0';//No Record Found - Username is available
    }
}
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready
{
    $("#username").change(function()
    { //if theres a change in the username textbox

        var username = $("#username").val();//Get the value in the username textbox
        if(username.length > 3)//if the lenght greater than 3 characters
        {
            $("#availability_status").html('Checking availability...');
            //Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

            $.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://mywebsite.com/auth/sign_up",
                data: "username="+ username,  //data
                success: function(server_response){

                    $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){

                        if(server_response == '0')//if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
                        {
                            $("#availability_status").html('<font color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
                           //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
                        }
                        else  if(server_response == '1')//if it returns "1"
                        {
                            $("#availability_status").html('<font color="red">Not Available </font>');
                        }

                    });
                }

            });

        }
        else
        {

            $("#availability_status").html('Username too short');
           //if in case the username is less than or equal 3 characters only
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

but then i write into username field i got error with firebug:
The action you have requested is not allowed.
[14:32:30.980] POST http://mywebsite.com/auth/sign_up [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 63ms]

any suggestion?

sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: if you are using codeigniter, use codeigniter libraries for accessing POST values, Session handling and Database operations please.

Comment: If you point your browser directly to http://mywebsite.com/auth/sign_up, do you get the same error?

Comment: add  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0); to the begining of the controller function and then try.You will see what exactly is the error.

Comment: Where is your PHP code from? It should be inside a method called `sign_up` in the `Auth` controller

Comment: Here's a tutorial on setting up login in CodeIgniter: http://www.codinglikeasir.com/codeigniter-tutorial-started-2/. The main shortcoming of the tutorial is that it uses the `md5` function to encrypt the passwords, which is not terrible but not the most secure way of encrypting passwords; for that I recommend this library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat.

Comment: and the preview firebug, how is the response from the server that returns the server?

Answer (score 1):

that's definitely not the way to do it for numerous reasons like

1. mysql_ extension is deprecated use PDO
2. if you are using codeigniter then use the Active Record Class for making db calls and the Input Class for getting POST variables

however id like to demonstrate a possible flow

**php**

```
$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['username'])) //If a username has been submitted
{
    //assume username is not available
    $status = false;
    $statusText = "Not Available";
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); //Some clean up :)

    //Query to check if username is available or not
    $isAvailable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($isAvailable)) {
        $status = true;
        $statusText = "Available";
    }

    $response = array(
        "status" => $status,
        "statusText" => $statusText
    );
}

return json_encode($response);
```

**js**

```
//alex >> comments usually go on top of the line you are commenting plus
//you dont have to comment every single line only when something 'big' or 'strange' happens

//When the dom is ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //if there is a change in the username textbox
    $("#username").change(function()
    {
        //Get the value in the username textbox
        var username = $("#username").val();
        //alex >> caching the div so i dont call it every time which improves performance
        var statusDiv = $("#availability_status");

        //if the length greater than 3 characters
        if(username.length > 3)
        {
            //TODO Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"
            statusDiv.html('Checking availability...');

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://mywebsite.com/auth/sign_up",
                data : "username=" + username,
                success : function(server_response)
                {
                    var color = "red";
                    var statusText = "an error occurred !";

                    server_response = JSON.parse(server_response);

                    if(server_response)
                    {
                        statusText = server_response.statusText;

                        if(server_response.status)
                            color = "green";
                    }
                    statusDiv.html("span class='" + color + "'" + statusText + "span");
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //if in case the username is less than or equal 3 characters only
            statusDiv.html('Username too short');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

just remember to make span a proper tag because the 'smart' editor is killing the whole tag

`statusDiv.html("<span class='" + color + "'>" + statusText + "</span>");`

which reminds me !

always check for empty :P

Comment: I just wanted to note, again, that the PHP code should be inside a method called `sign_up` in the `Auth` controller.

Comment: now looks perfect, but it dosn't work, i got error: [15:27:43.670] TypeError: server_response is null @ http://website.com/register/

Comment: Try adding an `else` branch to `if(isset($_POST['username']))` that sets `status` to false, just to make sure you're never getting a null result from the server.

Comment: i think it dosn't work, becouse i allways get: span class='red'undefinedspan

Comment: did you replace the statusDiv line with the one at the end of the answer also did you update both snippets ?

Comment: alex: yes i update both snippets, and statusDiv line, now i allways got this: undefined in red color

Comment: can you verify that POST['username'] is submitted and holds a value ? first checked in firebug if it is listed under Params tab and then try to var_dump it in php another idea try removing the json_encode function